# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsFossDebugKotlin'. > Internal compiler error

Tags: android, kotlin, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have created espresso UI tests and setup the CircleCI to run them. The tests are running successfully on emulator locally on my machine and also on a real device. But the build is failing when I try to run them on CircleCI throwing Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsFossDebugKotlin'. The error comes when command ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest is run by CircleCI.
You can get more details [here](https://circleci.com/gh/GOVINDDIXIT/Rocket.Chat.Android/427)

> > Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsFossDebugKotlin FAILED
> >     e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression at (43,44) in /home/circleci/project/app/src/main/java/chat/rocket/android/authentication/registerusername/presentation/RegisterUsernamePresenter.kt
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.logOrThrowException(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:241)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:212)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:91)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:162)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:133)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:145)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:111)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:90)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getType(ExpressionTypingServices.java:127)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolvePropertyInitializer(BodyResolver.java:880)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveProperty(BodyResolver.java:750)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:84)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:121)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:125)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:135)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:63)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:145)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:104)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:384)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:70)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:131)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:103)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:364)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:597)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:455)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1023)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1065)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1022)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:454)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >         at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
> >         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
> >         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type: ErrorScope{Error scope for class  with arguments: org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.IndexedParametersSubstitution@3822e4c9}
> >     [ERROR : Value]
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.SimpleTypeImpl.(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:119)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleTypeWithNonTrivialMemberScope(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:64)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:53)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:141)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:126)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace$default(TypeSubstitution.kt:118)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.convertPossiblyAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:64)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.convertPossiblyAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:61)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.transformAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:24)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorResolver.transformAnonymousTypeIfNeeded(DescriptorResolver.java:1011)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorResolver.lambda$inferReturnTypeFromExpressionBody$4(DescriptorResolver.java:1205)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:346)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:402)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.DeferredType.getDelegate(DeferredType.java:78)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.WrappedType.getConstructor(KotlinType.kt:76)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.isConstructedFromGivenClass(KotlinBuiltIns.java:823)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.isArray(KotlinBuiltIns.java:781)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt.isArrayOfNothing(TypeUtils.kt:87)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.checkers.CallReturnsArrayOfNothingChecker.containsArrayOfNothing(CallReturnsArrayOfNothingChecker.kt:35)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.checkers.CallReturnsArrayOfNothingChecker.check(CallReturnsArrayOfNothingChecker.kt:27)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallCompleter.completeCall(CallCompleter.kt:88)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCallOrGetCachedResults(CallResolver.java:609)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.lambda$computeTasksAndResolveCall$0(CallResolver.java:208)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:91)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.computeTasksAndResolveCall(CallResolver.java:206)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.computeTasksAndResolveCall(CallResolver.java:196)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveFunctionCall(CallResolver.java:322)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getResolvedCallForFunction(CallExpressionResolver.kt:95)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getCallExpressionTypeInfoWithoutFinalTypeCheck(CallExpressionResolver.kt:217)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getUnsafeSelectorTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.kt:332)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getSafeOrUnsafeSelectorTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.kt:369)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallExpressionResolver.getQualifiedExpressionTypeInfo(CallExpressionResolver.kt:462)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.visitQualifiedExpression(BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java:715)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.visitQualifiedExpression(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:371)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher$ForDeclarations.visitQualifiedExpression(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:45)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor.visitDotQualifiedExpression(KtVisitor.java:302)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtDotQualifiedExpression.accept(KtDotQualifiedExpression.kt:31)
> >         at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:173)
> >         ... 61 more

Comment: Hi bro did you find the solution

Comment: It's a memory issue, may be increasing circle ci's memory can fix this. You can upvote the ques if you are facing the same situation may be someone can answer a better approach.

Comment: where i should i need to increase the circle ci's memory

Comment: To increase memory you have to first buy a paid plan, Free plan only have 4gb of ram